# $wpdb->insert not working in any way

Tags: wpdb

I know this type of question has been asked over and over, but I couldn't find a solution for my problem, so I hope you can help me. I am using WP 3.3. and I have created a custom table. Now I want to insert some data into it, but I can't get it working. This is my code:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "my_data";
$wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
            'my_id'     => NULL,
        'my_day'    => $day,
        'my_month'  => $month,
        'my_abbr'   => $abbr,
        'my_venue'  => $venue,
        'my_geo'    => $geo_one.", ".$geo_two,
        'my_artist' => $artist,
        'my_link'   => $link
                )
                );
```

I am trying to insert data for several hours now without luck. To my eyes the code is correct, but I guess I am just mussing something important here. Any pointers would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Use `$wpdb->print_error();` in the next line to insert and check if it throws any errors.

Comment: Many thanks. $wpdb->show_errors() did not show anything but print_error() pointed exactly what the problem was!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When `$wpdb` method doesn't perform as it should it is likely issue with resulting SQL query (because of wrong input or something else).

Follow [`wpdb reference in Codex`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors) for troubleshooting:

- enable database error display via `$wpdb->show_errors()`
- check what query is being formed and run via `$wpdb->last_query`

Answer (score -1):

The `wpdb`-class does not have an insert method. It would be best if you didn't use the query; see the codex, and you don't find this function `insert()` - http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

An example of inserting a custom table on WPDB; use a default `CREATE TABLE`-SQL Syntax and create with the `query()` of `wpdb` the table with your values.

```
        $table = $GLOBALS['wpdb'] -> prefix . 'my_data';
        $GLOBALS['wpdb'] -> query(
            "CREATE TABLE $table (
            called_by varchar(96) NOT NULL,
            my_name varchar(96) NOT NULL,
            my_type varchar(15) NOT NULL,
            first_call int(11) NOT NULL,
            arg_count tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
            file_name varchar(128) NOT NULL,
            line_num smallint NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (first_call, my_name) )"
        );
```

To insert this source, use the `register_activation_hook()`-hook; only on activation, the plugin will install the table if it doesn't exist. On `register_uninstall_hook()` I delete custom tables.

Comment: [`wpdb` does have `insert()` method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows)